# How to apply OpenCV filter on a specific drawn region of an image in Kivy?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, kivy

I'm working on a Kivy application that displays an image and allows the user to draw rectangles on it using the rectangle attribute of Kivy.

Here's the code I'm using to achieve this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.image import Image


class CanvasExample(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.image = Image(source='sampleImg.jpg', size_hint=(None, None), size=(800, 600))
        self.add_widget(self.image)

        # Initialize variables
        self.start_pos = None
        self.rectangles = []

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.start_pos = touch.pos

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if self.start_pos is not None:
                # Compute the rectangle
                x, y = self.start_pos
                width = touch.pos[0] - x
                height = touch.pos[1] - y
                rect = Rectangle(pos=(x, y), size=(width, height))

                # Add the rectangle to the list
                self.rectangles.append(rect)

                # Add the rectangle to the image
                with self.image.canvas:
                    Color(1, 0, 0, 0.13)  # red color
                    Rectangle(pos=(x, y), size=(width, height))

                self.start_pos = None


class TheLab(App):
    def build(self):
        return CanvasExample()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TheLab().run()
```

I now want to isolate the specific drawn region and apply an OpenCV filter (such as Canny edge detection) to it. I want to update the image so that the drawn region contains the filtered image, and the rest of the image is the same.

I have tried to isolate the specific region using the position attribute, but it returns negative coordinates:

```
def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if self.selected_rect:
        # Get coordinates of selected rectangle
        x, y = self.selected_rect.pos
        w, h = self.selected_rect.size
        x, y, w, h = int(x), int(y), int(w), int(h)
        
        # Extract portion of image within the selected rectangle
        img_subset = self.img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        
        # Apply canny edge detection to the subset
        edges = cv2.Canny(img_subset, 100, 200)
        
        # Create mask for edges
        edge_mask = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        edge_mask[:, :, 0] = edges
        edge_mask[:, :, 1] = edges
        edge_mask[:, :, 2] = edges
            
        # Replace subset in original image with the edge mask
        self.img[y:y+h, x:x+w] = np.where(edge_mask > 0, edge_mask, img_subset)
        
        # Update Kivy texture and Image widget with modified image
        self.texture = self.convert_to_texture(self.img)
        self.image.texture = self.texture
        
        # Reset selected rectangle
        self.selected_rect = None
```

Comment: @ZachLagden How are code fences not "proper inline code blocks"? They are one of the two methods mentioned in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I'll admit that edit didn't really matter too much, it's just how I prefer things to look. No harm done, the question was still improved.